# Qual a origem dos prefixos met- et- prop- but- usados na química orgânica?

Tags: etimologia

Na nomenclatura utilizada na química orgânica usa-se um prefixo para denotar a quantidade de átomos de Carbono na cadeia principal. A partir de 5 átomos, os prefixos são de acordo com o que eu esperaria da Língua Portuguesa:

- 5: *pent-*
- 6: *hex-*
- 7: *hept-*
- 8: *oct-*

Estranhamente para os casos onde a cadeia principal contém de 1 a 4 Carbonos, [os prefixos utilizados](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu%C3%ADmica_org%C3%A2nica#Prefixo) são:

- 1: *met-*
- 2: *et-*
- 3: *prop-*
- 4: *but-*

São exemplos de uso deste prefixos os álcoois *metanol* e *etanol* e os gases *propano* e *butano*.

Gostaria de saber a origem etimológica destes prefixos, pois nunca ouvi-os em outros casos, tais como um *but-campeão* (ao invés de *tetra-campeão*) ou um *prop-mestre* (ao invés de *trimestre*).

Comment: Butcampeão é ótima, acho que vou passar a usar. E também etcicleta, etquini, propciclo, etruta e, claro, propiângulo e butaedro. E Metversidade e metverso.

Comment: @LuísHenrique, fenomenais neologismos! Mas fiz essas sugestões antes de ter a resposta e saber que estes prefixos nao têm origem na quantidade de átomos;-)

Comment: Propi-legal....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os elementos *met-, et-, prop-* e *but-* não se referem aos números um, dois, três e quatro em geral, mas a grupos com esse número de átomos de carbono. A sua origem está em nomes latinos e gregos ou de origem latina e grega onde o composto foi identificado.

## ***Met-***

O antepositivos ***met-*** e ***metil-***, ou *meth-, methyl-* antes das reformas ortográficas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil, vêm do grego *méthu* ‘bebida fermentada (vinho, cerveja)’ e *húlē* ‘madeira’ (Houaiss, 2003; [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=methylene&allowed_in_frame=0) diz *methy* e *hyle*). Foi em 1834 que o químico francês Jean-Baptiste Dumas forjou o nome *méthylène* a partir destes elementos gregos [(CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/m%C3%A9thyl%C3%A8ne), por encontrar o composto em alcool de madeira; *meth-* (mais tarde *met-* em português), entendido com a parte vinda de *méthu, methy*, foi depois usado como antepositivo na formação de outras palavras ([Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=methylene&allowed_in_frame=0)).

## *Et-*

O antepositivo ***et-*** vem originalmente de ***éter*** (Houaiss, 2003). *Éter* vem do latim *aether* e grego *aither* ‘ar mais elevado e puro; céu’. Em 1730 o químico alemão Frobenius analisou o composto C2H5-O-C2H5, onde figuram unidades de dois átomos de carbono, e chamou-lhe *spiritus vini aethereus* ‘espírito de vinho etéreo’ ([CNTRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ether) e [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Sigmund_Frobenius)), donde o seu nome comum *éter* ou *éter etílico*. Em 1834 o químico alemão Justus Liebig formou o nome *ethyl*, de *ether* e *yl* do grego *hyle* ‘madeira, substância’ [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol#Etymology) para designar o grupo C2H5-. A partir daí apareceram em várias línguas muitos nomes para compostos químicos usando o antepositivo *eth*, que no português passou a *et* com as reformas ortográficas de 1911 em Portugal e 1943 no Brasil.

## *But-*

***But-*** aparece nos antepositivos ***butan(o)-, butil-*** e ***butir(o)***, vindo todos do latim *butyrum* e grego *boúturon* ‘manteiga’ (Houaiss, 2003). Foi em 1819 que o francês Michel Chevreul cunhou o nome *acide butyrique,* ‘ácido butanoico’ [(CNTRL)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/butyrique), cuja molécula tem quatro átomos de carbono [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyric_acid).

## *Prop-*

Esse ***prop-*** vem do inglês *propane* (1866, [Etymoline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=propane) e [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propane)), que por sua vez vem do francês *propionique* (1847, [CNTRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/propionique)). Foi o químico francês Jean-Baptiste Dumas que cunhou em 1847 o nome *acide propionique*, ‘ácido propanoico’, composto cuja molécula tem três átomos de carbono. O nome *propionique* foi formado do grego *protos* ‘primeiro’ e *pion* ‘gordura’, por este ácido ser o menor ou primeiro na série de ácidos gordos ([CBTRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/propionique) e [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propionic_acid)).